# react-bootstrap - Form.Check (radio button) is checked even after reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

The radio button ( from react-bootstrap Form.Check ) is checked even if the value of checked prop becomes false after clicking reset button ( reset only runs **resetForm** method provided by formik ). This is used inside formik and it is re-rendered when redux state is changed.
Below is the code which creates this issue, in which I have also added a debugging line to show the value of the checked condition in images attached.

```
const handleSubmitClick = (_data: any) => {
  dispatch(setUploadSatus({submitted: true, form: _data}));
}
const status = useSelector(uploadSatus);
const genderOptions = [
  { value: 'Female', label: 'Female' },
  { value: 'Male', label: 'Male' },
 ];
 *
 **some code**
 *
<Formik
      onSubmit={data => handleSubmitClick(data)}
      initialValues={{
        age: '',
        gender: '',
        condition: '',
        symptoms: [],
        files: [],
        ...status.form
      }}
      validationSchema={schema}
    >
      {({
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        setFieldValue,
        resetForm,
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        setTouched,
        initialTouched
      }) => (
               <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} onReset={resetForm}>
                {genderOptions.map((gender: any) => {
                  return <>
                  {values.gender === gender.value ? 'True' : 'Flase'}
                  <Form.Check
                    inline
                    type="radio"
                    name="gender"
                    value={gender.value}
                    checked={values.gender === gender.value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label={gender.label}
                    disabled={status.submitted}
                    isValid={touched.gender && !errors.gender && !status.submitted}
                    isInvalid={touched.gender && !!errors.gender}
                  /></>
                <Button type="reset" variant="info" className="btn-block">
                  Reset
                </Button>
               </Form>
             )
       }
</Formik>
```

Initially before clicking the reset button,
[image]

After clicking reset,
[image]

Comment: Can you give us some more code? We don't even see handlechange function.

Comment: @varjod handlechange is provided by formik